# Passing key-value pair jquery array into .NET MVC action

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have an jquery key-value pair array as following:

- The array is filled when check-boxes are checked
- If a checkbox is unchecked, item will be removed from there

The code for that part is:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.chkItem', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                product_ids[$(this).attr('id')] = "Checked";
            } else {
                delete product_ids[$(this).attr('id')];
            }
        });
```

This works fine, let's head onto the next part. Now I'm trying to send all these ID's from my view into a controller "Analyze" and action "Index", which looks as following:

```
  $(".btnAnalyze").click(function () {
            if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(product_ids) == true) {
                alert("Array is empty");
            }
            else {

                var postData = { values: product_ids };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Analyze/Index",
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.Result);
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true
                });

            }
        });
```

And my action looks like following:

```
 public ActionResult Index(List<string> values)
        {
            string id2= "";
            foreach (var id in values)
            {
                id2= id;
            }
// I'm trying to fetch the ID values here that I added into the array, but I'm not sure how... 

}
```

With this current method the contents of List values is

```
"[object Object]"
```

which is not what I want.. I need all of the ID's sorted out nicely into the list as I send them to the Action Index...

Can someone help me out with this???

Comment: Anyony has any idea how to do this ???

Comment: First of all, slow down. Stack Overflow is not your personal answer slave. Secondly, `product_ids` is not an array; it's an object with keys that are your IDs. You might do some research on [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: Could you provide a more reasonable answer... I do realize it's not y personal answer slave, nor I ever considered that to be... Now onto my first question, can you provide an answer so that I can accept it if it's correct...

Comment: You certainly imply that it is when you ask for answers less than three minutes after you've posted the question... Please read [ask] and take the [tour]. Why don't you try applying the hint I gave you? `Object.keys(product_ids)`.

Comment: Well my apologies if you understood it like that, I didn't mean it that way... And yes I just tried your hint and it works like a charm! :) It'd be better if you wrote an answer so I could accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an object, not an array, and it is thus saying that it's an object. You have two choices:

1. Use an actual array:

   ```
   var product_ids = [];
   $(document).on('click', '.chkItem', function () {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       product_ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
     } else {
       product_ids.splice(product_ids.indexOf($(this).attr('id')), 1);
     }
   });
   ```
2. Continue using an object and use `Object.keys` to get just the property names (which are the IDs in your code):

   ```
   var postData = { values: Object.keys(product_ids) };
   ```

Personally, I like #1 because it's more explicit that you're capturing the ids of the checked checkboxes, and the values of the object's properties is always `"Checked"` rather than anything meaningful, but hey, JavaScripts' flexible like that :).

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log(data.Result)` to debug instead of `alert(data.Result)`, because `alert(data.Result)` **stringifies** your variable to `[object Object]`. To open up console press `F12`

Comment: Can you show what you receive on the server side and back at ajax `success` callback?